# Let $S_n$ be a simple symmetric random walk. Show that $P(S_1S_2...S_{2n} \neq 0) = P(S_{2n} = 0)$

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let $S_n$ be a simple symmetric random walk. Show that $P(S_1S_2...S_{2n} \neq 0) = P(S_{2n} = 0)$

I'm not sure how to approach this. A hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question was unfortunately rather vague on this, but I was under the impression that $S_1S_2...S_{2n} \neq 0$ meant that nowhere in the first 2n steps of the walk does it hit $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_0=\min\{n\ge 1:S_n=0\}$. It [can be shown](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Egenovese/class/iprob-S06/notes/lec5-calcs.pdf) that for $n\ge 1$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(T_0=2n)=\frac{1}{2n-1}\mathsf{P}(S_{2n}=0)=\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathsf{P}(T_0>2n)=\sum_{j>n}\frac{1}{2j-1}\binom{2j}{j}2^{-2j}=\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}=\mathsf{P}(S_{2n}=0).
$$

---

Alternatively, set $q_n:=\mathsf{P}(S_n=0)$ and $p_n:=\mathsf{P}(T_0>n)$, and for $j\le n$ let
$$
A_j=\{S_{2j}=0,S_{2j+1}\ne 0,\ldots,S_{2n}\ne 0\}.
$$
Then,
$$
\mathsf{P}(A_j)=\mathsf{P}(S_{2j}=0)\times \mathsf{P}(T_0>2(n-j))=q_{2j}p_{2(n-j)},
$$
and since $A_0,\ldots,A_{2n}$ are disjoint,
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n q_{2j}p_{2(n-j)}=\sum_{j=0}^n \mathsf{P}(A_j)=1,
$$
which implies that $q_{2n}=p_{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you. This is my fault for not being clear, but it seems that they wanted more of a bijective type of proof as the result $P(T_0 = n) = \frac{1}{n-1}$ is rather involved. Not sure if one exists though.

Comment: @Math_Day It exists :)

Comment: How did you go from $ \sum_{j=0}^n q_{2j}p_{2(n-j)}=\sum_{j=0}^n P(A_j)=1$ to $q_{2n}=p_{2n}$?

Comment: @Math_Day Use induction and compute $p_{2n}$ when $q_{2j}=p_{2j}$ for $j<n$.